# What is the right way in using SQLite when changing activities in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two activities.
Activity 1 - connects to the database and gets some data.
Activity 2 - Connects to the database and pushes new data.

There is a button that opens activity 2 from activity 1.

When i open the database connection in activity 1, should i close it before opening activity 2 and then reopen the connection in activity 2?

OR , Is there a way to open the database connection in activity 1 and then just pass the connection to other activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest these three solutions

- You can close db every `onStop()` invocation and open when `onStart()` called in your activities, but it is not a good solution
- Wrap your database in some [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), for example call it DataSource or DataAccessObject. Its look like a global variable - one point to accessing application's data, I am especially recommend this way
- May be you don't need connection to db in the second activity. [Start second activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) by `yourIntent.startActivityForResult()`, then you should to return new data from second to first by intent and add it to db in `onActivityResult()` method

P.S. sorry for my bad English